# Overriding routes set by packages (Laravel 5.2)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using laravel 5.2 with the sentinel package (`rydurham/Sentinel`).
This package sets some routes automatically, namely:

```
Route::get('login', ['as' => 'sentinel.login', 'uses' => 'SessionController@create']);
Route::get('logout', ['as' => 'sentinel.logout', 'uses' => 'SessionController@destroy']);
Route::get('sessions/create', ['as' => 'sentinel.session.create', 'uses' => 'SessionController@create']);
Route::post('sessions/store', ['as' => 'sentinel.session.store', 'uses' => 'SessionController@store']);
```

In order to add my custom logic, I created a new session controller, and attempted to override the routes doing the following:

```
Route::get('login', ['as' => 'sentinel.login', 'uses' => 'AuthController@create']);
Route::get('sessions/create', ['as' => 'sentinel.session.create', 'uses' => 'AuthController@create']);
Route::post('sessions/store', ['as' => 'sentinel.session.store', 'uses' => 'AuthController@store']);
```

The problem laravel's routing seemingly favours the package routes. I could comment out the routes in the package, however this would make updating a pain.
How can I override the routes without modifying the package?
Thanks!

Comment: browse to vendor folder and check if there is any file similar to routes.php and remove the routes you wont need (just assuming this will work, never tested)

Comment: That was my original approach but during deployment this file would get reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable Sentinel default routes in `config/sentinel.php`

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Routing
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Sentinel provides default routes for its sessions, users and groups.
| You can use them as is, or you can disable them entirely.
|
*/
'routes_enabled' => true,
```

Comment: Oh, can't believe I missed this. Thanks!